# Warning when author has no post

Tags: warnings

i have a page who display the latest posts of an author. But when the author has no post i get a display message

> Warning: rsort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in ...

Here the script

```
function wpmu_latest_post_auther($authorId,$how_many = 10, $how_many_words = 50, $more_text = "[...]", $remove_html = true, $sort_by = 'post_date') {
global $wpdb;

//first, gat all blog id
$query = "SELECT blog_id FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE blog_id !='1'";
$blogs = $wpdb->get_col($query);

if ($blogs) {
    //we use blog id to loop post query
    foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
        $blogPostsTable = 'wp_'.$blog.'_posts';

         $db_query = "SELECT $blogPostsTable.ID,
                    $blogPostsTable.post_author,
                    $blogPostsTable.post_title,
                    $blogPostsTable.guid,
                    $blogPostsTable.post_date,
                    $blogPostsTable.post_content,
                    $blogPostsTable.post_modified,
                    $blogPostsTable.comment_count
                    FROM $blogPostsTable WHERE $blogPostsTable.post_status = 'publish'
                    AND $blogPostsTable.post_author = $authorId 
                    AND $blogPostsTable.post_type = 'post'";

        $thispos = $wpdb->get_results($db_query);

        foreach($thispos as $thispost) {
        if($sort_by == 'post_date') {
            $order = $thispost->post_date;
        }
        else{
            $order = $thispost->post_modified;
            }

            $post_dates[]           = $order;
            $post_guids[$order]     = $thispost->guid;
            $blog_IDs[$order]       = $blog;
            $post_IDs[$order]       = $thispost->ID;
            $post_titles[$order]    = $thispost->post_title;
            $post_authors[$order]   = $thispost->post_author;
            $post_contents[$order]  = $thispost->post_content;
            $comments[$order]       = $thispost->comment_count;
            }
        }


    rsort($post_dates);
    $union_results  = array_unique($post_dates);
    $ResultArray    = array_slice($union_results, 0, $how_many);

    foreach ($ResultArray as $date) {
        $ID                 = $post_IDs[$date];
        $blogID             = $blog_IDs[$date];
        $id_author          = $post_authors[$date];
        $post_url           = get_blog_permalink($blog_IDs[$date], $ID);/*$post_guids[$date];*/
        $post_title         = $post_titles[$date];
        $post_content       = $post_contents[$date];
        $post_date          = mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), $date);
        $post_time          = mysql2date(get_option('time_format'), $date);
        $total_comment      = $comments[$date];
        $user_info          = get_userdata($id_author);
        $author_blog_url    = get_blogaddress_by_id($user_info->primary_blog);
        $author_url         = $user_info->user_url;
        $author_email       = $user_info->user_email;

        if($user_info->first_name) {
            $author_name = $user_info->first_name.' '.$user_info->last_name;
        }
        else{
            $author_name = $user_info->nickname;
        }

        if($remove_html) {
            $post_content = wpmu_cleanup_post($post_content);
        }

        $results = array();

        $results['ID']              = $ID;
        $results['blogID']          = $blogID;
        $results['post_url']        = $post_url;
        $results['post_title']      = $post_title;
        $results['post_content']    = wpmu_cut_article_by_words($post_content, $how_many_words);
        if ($results['post_content'] != $post_content)
            $results['post_content'] .= sprintf('  <a href="%s">%s</a>', $post_url, $more_text);
        $results['author_blog_url'] = $author_blog_url;
        $results['author_url']      = $author_url;
        $results['author_email']    = $author_email;
        $results['author_name']     = $author_name;
        $results['post_date']       = $post_date;
        $results['post_time']       = $post_time;
        $results['comment_count']   = $total_comment;

        $returns[] = $results;
    }

    $latest_posts = wpmu_bind_array_to_object($returns);
    return $latest_posts;
} }
```

Is someone has an idea on how to not display the warning when the author as no post added.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the `rsort` bit in an if statement like this:

```
if (!empty($post_dates)) {
    rsort($post_dates);
} else { echo 'optional error message here'; }
```

This will check to see if the variable is empty first, and only run `rsort()` if it is not empty. This check works most of the time, but a false positive can sometimes occur if, for example, the variable is not actually an array but contains other data! (such as an error message). Alternatively, you may find this to work better in certain circumstances:

```
if ($post_dates != '') {
    rsort($post_dates);
}
```

This will only continue if the variable does not equal `null`, which isn't quite the same thing as being empty. There are other ways to check if the variable is what you want, for example `if (is_array($post_dates)) { do stuff }`.

Comment: Not sure if the rest of your page will continue to work without that `$post_dates` filled. Might need to do something "else" with your `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are grabbing the `blog_id` early in the piece what you can do is check to see whether the particular blog in question has any posts and if it does, proceed.

One  way to do this is by using the `get_blog_details()` function.

```
$blog = get_blog_details( $blod_id );
$total_posts = $blog->post_count;

if ($total_posts == O) {

// do nothing (eg. echo 'this author has no posts';) 

} else {

// your regular code here

}
```

By feeding `get_blog_details` the blog ID number, you gain access to a whole range of properties, one of which being `post_count` for which you can use within the above `if/else` conditional statement to run a check before prior to executing your function.

Thus you can now display a different result set/piece of information in instances where a user has no posts and where they do have posts your regular code will execute as per normal.

Alternatively the `count_user_posts()` function could be used, however the above should suffice in this instance.

For reference purposes you can find more information at;

- [`get_blog_details()` - Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_details)
- [`count_user_posts()` - Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts)

Hope that helps you.